# mySQL Stored Procedure to process tables list

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

Help needed here. I'm trying to get mySQL do the following:

1- Read a list of tables (e.g. 10)
2- Count the no. of rows in each
3- Print the result (after each count, or as a whole at the end).

Best I've managed is this SP:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`your.name`@`192.168.%` PROCEDURE `test`(name_table varchar(50))
BEGIN

SET @sqlText = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', name_table,' ;') ;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlText;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

 END
```

If I enter the table it gets it done. OK for one table, but not for 200. My problems are 2:

1) How do you copy or allocate the result of executing @sqlText **to a variable**, so that it can be printed?

2) How do you **iterate a table** (or any other repository) so that you can put all tables into one place? I've heard of cursors, still unsure how to use them in mySQL.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Look for ```SHOW TABLE STATUS``` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: Thanks Matt. I know the SHOW TABLE STATUS command. Unfortunately it doesn't give you the exact no. of rows, but only an approximate no. Check by yourself. That's the reason behind doing this SP.